# TypeError: init () takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, web-applications, webserver

I would appreciate if any one knows how to solve this error. I get this error while running the below code:

```
!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
##################################################
# GNU Radio Python Flow Graph
# Title: Top Block 22
# Generated: Tue Jul 23 15:54:16 2019
##################################################




from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import audio
from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from optparse import OptionParser
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, redirect, url_for
from random import randint


class top_block_22(gr.top_block):

    def __init__(self):
        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block 22")

        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate = 32000

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.blocks_add_xx = blocks.add_vff(1)
        self.audio_sink = audio.sink(32000, '', True)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_noise_source_x_0 = analog.noise_source_f(analog.GR_GAUSSIAN, 0.005, -42)

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_noise_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 2))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))
        self.connect((self.blocks_add_xx, 0), (self.audio_sink, 0))

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hex_color():
        return render_template("index.html")
@app.route('/valueofslider')
def slide():
    slide_val = request.args.get('slide_val')
    return top_block_22(slide_val)     


def main(top_block_cls=top_block_22, options=None):

    tb = top_block_cls()
    tb.start()

    try:
        raw_input('Press Enter to quit: ')
    except EOFError:
        pass
    tb.stop()
    tb.wait()

    samp_rate = int(slide_val) + 100
    print(samp_rate)
    return(slide_val) # Still need to return or get TypeError 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Error log:

```
fit-pc@fitpc-fitlet2:~$ python /home/fit-pc/my_flask_app/virtualenv/Slider/top_block_22.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 269-962-008
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2019 10:05:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2019 10:05:48] "GET /valueofslider?slide_val=6037 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/fit-pc/my_flask_app/virtualenv/Slider/top_block_22.py", line 56, in slide
    return top_block_22(slide_val)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Update:

Thank you all for your replies, but unfortunately none of them worked for me so far. Here is my index.html code DOCTYPE html html head meta harset="utf-8" title jQuery roundSlider - JS Bin

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Only html needed   -->
  <div id="slider"></div>

  <script>
    var val;
    $("#slider").roundSlider({
      radius: 215,
        min: 0,
        max: 40000,

      change: function () {
        var obj1 = $("#slider").data("roundSlider");
        val = obj1.getValue();
        value: 1
        $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
          slide_val: val
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Exactly as the error says, you are passing too many arguments to `top_block_22`. You haven't written it to accept the `slide_val` as an argument; even if you did, what are you intending to do with it?

Comment: you classe doesn't have argument but  when you call the class you are passing (slide_val) the call should be like this top_block_22() or you can do changes to take tghe value your passing

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand that comment. I told you where the error was happening.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I just noticed my comment, was just typo thing. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the log said more than enough . The error is here `return top_block_22(slide_val)`

that's normal, if you look up to the definition of the Class, it doesnt take any arguments, self will be provided by python but you don't really added any arguments to the definition and later you created an object and passed an argument to it that's why you are getting the Error

if you call the creation of object like this:
  `return top_block_22() # this would throw no Error`

Comment: I did like you said and still gives the same error.

Comment: but it must be another Error and not the same Error. I'm not looking at the whole code to see what it can provoke but sure if it have some interacting with another function or class than it ll certainly cause other errors

Answer (score 1):

You did not pass argument for top_block22 in `def __init__()`
  .Argument that you passed in indicated line is not recognized.

It should look like follows

```
def __init__(self, slide_value): 
    self.slide_value = slide_value
```

Comment: I changed it to what you recommended and gave me this error: TypeError: 'top_block_22' object is not callable

Comment: since your answer took away the error I would definitely accept as an answer. I will post the other generated error shortly.  Thanks s3nh.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that when you call `gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block 22")` you shouldn't pass `"Top Block 22"` to it.

As the error mentions, `__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: Please accompagny your -1 with an explanation so I can improve my answer.

Comment: Your answer is wrong; the error happens in the call to instantiate `top_block_22`, not in the super invocation

Comment: @Leogout, actually, your answer correct, it fixed it, though I got  TypeError: 'top_block_22' object is not callable. Thanks!